# Linear Algebra: Endomorphism & Projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following question (taken from Golan's text book on linear algebra,  chapter 7) in a recent exam:

"$\mathbb{F}$ is field. Explain whether there exists an endomorphism $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{F}^{3}$  which is not a projection such that $\alpha^{2}$ is a projection equal to neither $\sigma_{0}$ nor $\sigma_{1}$."

($\sigma_{0}$ and $\sigma_{1}$ are the identity elements for addition and multiplication respectively.)

I would appreciate any guidance on this problem as I failed to answer it correctly and no solutions were provided. Specifically, I'm  confused as to what exactly does a projection have to do with an endomorphism (which I understand). Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Golan's $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma_1$ are the endomorphisms $0$ and $\operatorname{id}$, respectively. So you are looking for an endomorphism $\alpha$ of $F^3$ such that $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\alpha \neq \operatorname{id}$ such that $\alpha^4 = \alpha^2$ (this is what it means that $\alpha^2$ is a projection) but $\alpha^2 \neq \alpha$ (this is what it means that $\alpha$ is not a projection). In other words, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ should divide $x^4 - x^2$ but not $x^2 - x$. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Now I understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\alpha =v\mapsto Mv$ with the following matrix
$$M=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0}$$
Then, with $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as the standard basis, we have
$$\alpha(e_1)=e_2,\ \alpha(e_2)=e_1,\ \alpha(e_3)=0$$
Thus, $\alpha^2$ is a projection to $\mathrm{span}(e_1, e_2)$, but $\alpha\ne\alpha^2$, thus $\alpha$ is not a projection.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. It really helps.

Answer (score 2):

Characterization of projections:

- If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, an endomorphism $T$ of $V$ is
  a projection if and only if $T^2=T$.

Next let $F$ be a field, let $V=F^3$, and let $A\in M_3(F)$ be given by
$$
A=
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0\cr
1 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 1
}
$$
Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^2(x-1)$, it follows that

- $A^2\ne A$, so $A$ is not a projection.$\\[4pt]$

  $A^4=A^2$, so $A^2$ is a projection.$\\[4pt]$

  $A^2\ne 0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $A^2\ne I$.$\\[4pt]$

hence $A$, regarded as an endomorphism of $V$, satisfies the specified requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Your detailed example really helps explain the problem.